# How to sum Timespan of subtraction between two datetimes in Linq when using group by?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datetime, timespan

I have items with the properties :

```
public int ClientId {get;set;}
public DateTime StartDateTime{get;set;}
public DateTime EndDateTime{get;set;}
```

And I want to calculate the total of the difference between all the datetimes of each client with group by , but this :

```
  var retVal  = (from t items group t by ClientId  into z     
                              select new
                              {
                                  ClientId = z.Key,
                                  TimeSpanClientTotal = z.Sum(h => (h.EndDateTime - h.StartDateTime))
                                  }).ToList();
```

Doesn't work since `Sum` doesn't work well for `TimeSpan` , which is the return value of the difference between two `DateTime`s object .

Any suggestion how can I get the total TimeSpan of each client ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work well"?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `Enumerable.Sum` [doesn't have a `Timespan` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum.aspx)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: It means that you cannot convert TimeSpan to Decimal , when you use `Sum` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Enumerable.Sum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum.aspx) is just an extension method you call on an IEnumerable. There is nothing special to it so you can easily create another extension method that sums timespans:

```
static class TimeSpanExtensions
{
    public static TimeSpan Sum<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> enumerable,
                                             Func<TSource,TimeSpan?> func )
    {
        return enumerable.Aggregate(TimeSpan.Zero, (total, it) =>
                                                    total+=(func(it)??TimeSpan.Zero);
    }
}
```

Assuming your class definition is

```
class Record
{
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDateTime { get; set; }

    public Record(int clientId, DateTime startDateTime, DateTime endDateTime)
    {
        ClientId = clientId;
        StartDateTime = startDateTime;
        EndDateTime = endDateTime;
    }
}
```

You can write the same code you would for the numeric types:

```
var items = new[] {
    new Record(1, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1)),
    new Record(1, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1)),
    new Record(1, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1))};
var total=items.Sum(h=>(h.EndDateTime-h.StartDateTime));

var grouped= (from t in items
                group t by t.ClientId into z
                select new
                {
                    ClientId = z.Key,
                    TimeSpanClientTotal = z.Sum(h => (h.EndDateTime - h.StartDateTime))
                }).ToList();
```

You can also use [Enumerable.Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548651%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) directly:

```
var total= items.Aggregate(TimeSpan.Zero, (current, it) => 
                               current += (it.EndDateTime-it.StartDateTime));
```

The code can be uglier but you can do a lot more than simple addition.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, all proposed solutions didn't work. They caused error related with LINQ restrictions. So, my workaround looks like this:

```
var appointments = (from apps in DbContext.ClientAppointments
                           where apps.StartDate.Value.Date == date.Date
                           select new
                           {
                               SpecialistId = apps.SpecialistId,
                               Duration = (apps.EndDate.Value - apps.StartDate.Value).TotalSeconds
                           }).ToList();

        var result = (from apps in appointments
                     group apps by apps.SpecialistId into g
                     select new AppointmentsDurationDailyDto
                      {
                          SpecialistId = g.Key ?? 0,
                          Date = date.Date,
                          Duration = g.Sum(apps => apps.Duration)
                      }).ToList();
```

In this solution first `.ToList();` is important to make next grouping statement on client. In case if you need to get `TimeSpan Duration` you can easily convert it back by using `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Duration)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .TotalMilliseconds Property

```
var retVal  = (from t items group t by ClientId  into z     
                              select new
                              {
                                  ClientId = z.Key,
                                  TimeSpanClientTotal = z.Sum(h => (h.EndDateTime - h.StartDateTime).TotalMilliseconds)
                                  }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like that:

```
 h.EndDateTime.Subtract(h.StartDateTime).TotalDays();
```